# Saving images into Neo4J

Tags: database, neo4j

As i have to use Neo4J in one of my project i tried to get some ideas on it. It stores the values in key-value pair manner. But i coudn't understand one thing that how to store images ?? In some situations we store the URL of the corresponding images in RDBMS. But in Graph databases what are the tricks ? Please someone provide me some good articles link or answer clearly.
Thanks.!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you actually need to store the entire image, or can you store a reference id to the image which exists on disk?

I ask this question because most likely you're going to store it as a byte array in the DB, and if you're never actually going to use the byte array for your analysis, then you may as well just store a reference.

If you are using it for comparison, say duplicate prevention, you can always store the MD5 or something.

Why do you need to store the image in the DB?

Comment: Nicholas, Thanks for your reply. Here according to the specification nothing is fixed till now but possibly there won't be any scenario to have image on the disk according to the architects. And i also know that storing byte array is quite expensive. Though it has advantages too. We can get back the images from byte array in compressed  form without diminished quality.

Comment: There may be other advantages of storing byte arrays. But as you suggested MD5, it looks like a better solution. Because i may need to avoid duplicates in DB. Can you please give me some good approach and steps to store MD5?? I need to show images in UI on user request or sometimes without request. Thanks.!!

Comment: Just store the MD5 as a string in the DB. Information you store in properties on Neo4j should be things you'll use for comparisons, or for query's. Rarely will you be using the actual image, but more of a reference to the image.

Comment: It makes sense to store the image in the property as is because as part of the database backup your valuable image will be part of that single backup VS backup DB, backup images, now store them in a way to make sure if you restore you get the the db and image backup that match each other.  Also logically if the image is equivalent to say the age property on the node why is the head shot picture of the node not stored as is just like the age of value? Because it's a technical/performance consideration.  Bottom line test both approaches.